# What is the cleanest and/or best way to create driver-like commands with multiple options in C#

Tags: c#

I have a HW data bit clock I would like to set to different modes in C#, but I am wondering the best way to implement this. Here is my current implementation, but using strings and string compares seems error prone. Is there a better way to do this?

```
int SetDAI_BCLK(int32 Hz, string mode)
{
     // int32 Hz Specifies the BCLK rate in Hz
     // string mode: "master" => master mode, "slave" => slave mode, "off" => clock off, "poll1" => special polling mode

     // Implementation here, use str compares to set the clock mode

     // return 1 if success, -1 if comm error, -2 if invalid clock settings, -3 if invalid string master
}
```

Edit: It works great if it's all in the same project, but what if I want to make use of functions in another project, using enums instead of strings. I can't figure out how to do it without hardcoding the enums in both projects.

Project A contains the enum definitions and references project B which contains the equipment functions. Project B doesn't know of these enums, and when I try to reference project A, I get a circular reference error and am not allowed to reference it. Is there anyway to reference just the one file? What's the best way to use the same enums across these two projects. Using VS 2013 Express.

Comment: Thought about using an enum?

Comment: best -> primary based opinion ...

Comment: `I am wondering the best way to implement this.`  `Is there a better way to do this?`  No you are the best :)))))

Comment: Seriouly opinion based... here another one: what you showing is nowhere close to reasonable public .Net friendly API - it is perfectly fine to internal details of implementation/interaction with C code, but if you are looking for nice usable and safe API - consider how you want it to be used and provide decently named classes/methods/properties instead of single method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say the least error prone implementation would be `enum`'s like so:

```
enum Mode
{
    Master = 1,
    Slave = 2,
    Off= 3,
    Poll1 = 4
}
enum Error
{
    Success = 1,
    CommError = -1,
    InvalidClockSettings = -2,
    InvalidStringMaster = -3
}
```

so then your method signature would look something like this

```
Error SetDAI_BCLK(Int32 Hz, Mode mode)
{
     //Do Work
}
```

But of course, more meaningful enum names might be in order, and you could reduce their size requirements by using `byte` (if you can change the numbers to all be positive) or `short`, like so:

```
enum Mode: short 
{
    ...
}
```

**Extra:**

Since you have a string for your mode, just to be thorough, if you need to use string values, then the fastest compare would be to check the first characters as you have 4 different starting characters, however, if you want to require the whole word, the best option I'm aware of is a culture invariant string compare in lower case ordinal like: `String.CompareOrdinal("poll1", mode);` with an expected result of `0`.

Comment: I'm not concerned about the run speed, but thanks for the added detail. The first example is exactly what I needed and was imagining there should be. Thanks a lot.

Comment: As far as naming goes, what's the best way to handle the naming of enums. Here is what I have so far, and I feel it's kind of clunky. enum Edut { a, b}   ----   Edut dut = Edut.a;

Comment: I generally suggest using an indicative word like `type` or `mode`, for example: `DAI_BCLKMode { Master, Slave, etc.... }` but really it's whatever you want, just make it clear and consistent.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using enums instead of both your string value and your return value.  They provide clear meaning as to what values are allowed or what a given return value indicates. For example:

```
enum DAIMode {
    Off,
    Master,
    Slave,
    Poll1
}
```

Comment: +1, that's the route I would take. One possible alternative (but it's possibly too high-level for such a low-level function): Depending on the exact meanings of the conditions associated with the return "magic values", throwing an exception instead of returning a value might be an appropriate means of signalling an error condition.